# Leaflet geoserver wms doesn't show on google map base layer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I have a site running Openlayers (base layer google and overlay wms in epsg4326 from geoserver).

The site works fine.

I've decided to try doing the same with leaflet , and from some reason I can't make the WMS layer show on google.

This is the code I used :

```
var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');

coords = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/Coords/wms", {
    layers: 'Test:Coords',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true        
});

var baseLayers = {
    "Google": googleLayer        
};

var overlays = {
    "Coords": coords
};

map = new L.Map('map2d', {
    center: new L.LatLng(32.05522664582287, 35.05812072269409),
    zoom: 9,        
    layers: [googleLayer, coords],
    zoomControl: true
});

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

The layer does appear on the layer switcher , but the image doesn't show on the map.

* UPDATE *****

I've tried force declaring the layer in geoserver as EPSG3857 and still with no luck.

Comment: If the WMS does not serve in Web Mercator CRS, it's not compatible with Google maps.

Comment: So if it works in Openlayers , it doesn't mean it works in leaflet ?

Comment: If it works in Openlayers, I don't think the WMS is limited to epsg:4326.

Comment: OL works fine with base map google and overlay 4326 , and leaflet don't . I've created new basemap in 4326 and now wms shown. But i have different problem. Please take a look:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79056/leaflet-wms-offset-on-zoom-out

Comment: If you've solved this, you should either accept an answer that helped, or add your own answer that shows what the problem was and how you fixed it, @Alophind.

Comment: The url looks suspicious, without `geoserver` in it... just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I add a standard GeoServer WMS layer:

```
    var layer = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://host.example.com/geoserver/service/wms', {
        layers: 'workspace:layername',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        maxZoom: 20
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);
```

The only significant difference is the 'transparent: true' in mine, vs text in yours.

One way to test is by using the browser debug tools to look at what the image URLs are, and testing them individually. You may see an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the WMS CRS. Something similar to

```
var wms_layer = new L.TileLayer.WMS("http://somewms", {
            layers: 'layername',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: 'TRUE',
            version: '1.1.1',
            srs: 'EPSG:3857',
            attribution: 'some text'
        });
```

Comment: tried : 
crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857

With no luck.