# Leaflet wms offset on zoom out

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet

I have Leaflet map with base layer (epsg4326) and wms layer of gps point (also epsg4326).
I've noticed when I zoom out , the gps point offset to the left.

Any idea why it happens ?

Here you can see that when I zoom out the symbol moves left each zoom.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code:

```js
function initLeaflet() {   

    osm = L.tileLayer.wms(geoserver + "/OSM/wms", {
        layers: 'OSM',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    });

    coords = L.tileLayer.wms(geoserver + "/coords/wms", {
        layers: 'Roham:DeviceInfo',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true        
    });

    var baseLayers = {
        "osm": osm
    };

    var overlays = {
        "coords": coords
    };

    map = new L.Map('map2d', {
        center: new L.LatLng(32.05522664582287, 35.05812072269409),
        zoom: 9,
        layers: [osm, coords],
        zoomControl: true
    });

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
}
```